# Taking Multiple User Inputs and Displaying as a String Below

Tags: php, html, forms, text, input

I'm pretty new to this, but I'll try my best to explain what I need help with.

I am trying to take user input in a text box form and when they press 'submit' add it to a paragraph below.

As an example, if we have a text box form with a submit button and I type 'yes' and you type 'no', a paragraph below would then display 'yes no'. If John came two days later and typed 'maybe' into the text box then hit submit, the paragraph below would display 'yes no maybe'.

I know a lot of HTML and CSS and am still learning PHP and Javascript (and struggling to learn how to store data), so simplest terms possible here, please. I've been trying to learn to do this on stack overflow, but I feel pretty over my head with this one.

Comment: You could probably do this reading from and writing to a text file, although that would kind of limit it next to what you could do with a database.

Comment: This could be easily implemented using Javascript only. No PHP Required. Learn about the `value` and `text` property in javascript. It will solve your queries.